# Is there any better ways to describe data structure using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am thinking is there any better way to describe my data structure when using javascript.

Recently, I use `redux` to manage my application state.

Here is my case, I define an array:

```
const recommendDoctorTabs = []; //My colleague don't know the data structure.
function recommendDoctorTabsReducer(state = recommendDoctorTabs, action) {/**/}
```

at runtime, the fulfilled `recommendDoctorTabs` data structure like below:

```
const recommendDoctorTabs = [
  // { id: 1, name: '国内医生', type: 1 },
  // { id: 2, name: '海外医生', type: 2 }
];
```

I want to my colleague know the data structure at development stage, **not runtime stage**.

My way is use comment like above.

I know `typescript`-`interface` and `flow` will do this work better.

But I want to know is there any better ways do this work using `javascript`.

Comment: JSON seems to be the standard. are you asking about a better way?  TypeScript will bring Object Oriented concepts to your JS

Comment: Yes, if you want to describe your data format to your colleagues, a comment is a good way to do it. You could write code that would validate the data structure at runtime, e.g. check that it has the `id`, `name`, and `type` properties you listed. It's a bit unclear what the actual question is here.